# Help with Ubuntu, VMware Fusion, and OpenVPN Connect. Ubuntu Applications won't open

Tags: 22.04, vpn, vmware, mac, openvpn

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine running on VMware Fusion, on my mac. It was running fine, but I recently had to download OpenVPN Connect on my mac to use it with a class Im taking. Now Im trying to use the virtual machine, and Ubuntu wont open applications. I cant open simple things, like firefox, or vs code. I click on it and nothing happens.

Then I decided to restart the machine and when it did all applications were GONE! Then I restarted several times out of desperation, and now they are back (explain that) but they still won't open.

Besides installing OpenVPN, the only other thing thats happening are these popups on ubutu notifying me about limited space in the hard disk, but that was happening before and everything was working then. I dont have screenshots saved on VMware to restore the previous state because up until now I didnt know that was a thing.

I have PaloAlto Global Protect VPN as well, on both my mac and Ubuntu. It was installed for another class Im taking right.
None of the VPNs are actually running.

One more thing, I tried to find a way around to run X11 on my mac because we are using SFML C++ on my class and I thought that it would be good if I could actually use my mac for development instead of Ubuntu. I did get things like the xclock running but I couldnt figure out how to install SFML so I ditched and uninstalled everything related to that.

Does anyone know if there is a correlation and if there is a way to fix it?
Thank you